# How to read and understand 'Unexpected type(s)' problem in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to split a String based on the symbol: `|` and further split each String in it on a `:` and convert the result into a dictionary as below.

```
column_data = 'component_id:numeric(15,0)|name:character varying(30)|operation_num:numeric(15,0)|component_item:numeric(15,0)|item_number:character varying(800)|last_update_date:timestamp without time zone|last_updated_by:numeric(15,0)|creation_date:timestamp without time zone|created_by:numeric(15,0)|item_num:numeric|component_quantity:numeric|component_yield_factor:numeric|component_remarks:character varying(240)|effectivity_date:date|change_notice:character varying(10)'

column_names = dict(item.split(":") for item in gp_column_data.split("|"))
```

But I see a warning on the IDE that says:

```
Unexpected type(s): (Generator[List[str], Any, None]) Possible types: (Mapping) (Iterable[Tuple[Any, Any]])
```

The image can be seen below:
[image]

The same logic worked fine on Python shell but when I put the logic on IDE, the line highlights.
`gp_column_data` is a str that I am receiving as a method parameter.

```
def fix_source_columns(gp_column_data: str, precision_columns:str):
    column_names = dict(item.split(":") for item in gp_column_data.split("|"))
```

I am new to Python and see these messages often on IDE.
Could anyone let me know if this is an error message ? If so how can I fix the problem ?

Comment: The IDE is smart enough to warn you that `item.split(":")` might output an iterable with a single element in case `item` does not contain `:` (or more than 2 if there are multiple `:`). In this case, `dict` will fail because it expects an iterable in which all elements have exactly 2 elements (which is exactly what `Iterable[Tuple[Any, Any]]` in the warning means)

Comment: Got it. So this is a warning of a 'might be' case & unless you are absolutely sure of the logic & data used here, this warning (not an error) is nothing to be concerned about. Am I right ?

Comment: That's correct.. I'll make that an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The IDE is smart enough to warn you that `item.split(":")` might output an iterable with a single element in case `item` does not contain `:` (or more than 2 if there are multiple `:`). In these cases, `dict` will fail because it expects an iterable in which all elements have exactly 2 elements (which is exactly what `Iterable[Tuple[Any, Any]]` in the warning means).